# React-Native: No children allowed in my <image></image>

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, background

I'm having an issue with my code.

I'm not allowed to put anything in between my image tags, but I need to in order to load in the rest of my application.

```
class BackgroundImage extends Component {
render() {
    return(
        <Image source={require('./img/Sunny.jpg')}
              style={styles.backgroundImage}>
                  {this.props.children}
        </Image>
    )
}
}
```

This is the code I'm using, but for another class-mate it works just fine.
I can't find anything special in his code, sadly.

Here is the error:
[image error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvstp.png).

EDIT: As it stands right now I put  tags around my whole code.
The only thing that gets loaded in is the background-image and nothing else.

I'm just trying to add a background to my application, it's giving my a haaard time. Any help will be very appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:

Extra pictures of my horrid code:

[Start of render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZsCp.png)

[End of render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb3Z0.png)

[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3u8a.png)

This is what I have right now. In my code there are only `<Text>` and `<View>` with `this.state.x`

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lRbW.png)

[Attempt with Tim's code (failed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1vxU.png)

Comment: You can't add a children to an Image

Comment: @LucaZiegler The website that made the 'tutorial' for this piece of code has it working just fine. Same goes for my classmate. So confused.

Comment: You can try it with ImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a View around your Image and positioned it as absolute, because your are not allowed to pass children to image tag.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import BackgroundImage from './BackgroudImage';

class MainApp extends Component {

render() {
    return (
        <BackgroundImage>
            <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent', fontSize: 30 }}> Test </Text>
        </BackgroundImage>
    );
  }
}
export default MainApp;
```

And here your BackgroundImage Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native'; 
import background from '../../img/test.jpg';

class BackgroundImage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, position: 'relative' }}>
            {this.props.children}
            <Image 
            source={background}
            style={{ zIndex: -1, position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, resizeMode: 'cover' }} 
            />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
export default BackgroundImage;
```

And here the result:

[image]

Edit: example

Comment: With your code I'm getting the error-message that this.props.children is a reserved word.

Comment: Do you pass your BackgroundImage Component children? For example like 
<BackgroundImage >
<Text> This is a text </Text>
</BackgroundImage>

Comment: Yeah. I use the BackgroundImage in my main component surrounding the rest of the code. But right now it only loads in the background image and leaves the rest untouched.

Comment: Could u please provide more code and maybe a screenshot ?

Comment: Added the pictures. Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever tried a simple example, like i stated above? It's easier to debug simple examples. Maybe create a new empty project and then try again. And maybe remove your other styles and just try mine.

Comment: Okay, tried it. Just your code (screenshot added) "Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YodaNode to a parent without a measure function." Is the error I'm getting. I'll try to see what else might work.

Comment: i will provide you a working example as soon as i'm at home (approximately in 2 hours). Maybe you can than adapt my solution ;)

Comment: Ohh, thank you very much!
Until then I'll be trying to get it working.

Comment: THANK YOU. It all works now! I had to put the `{this.props.children` under the image, else it loaded the wrong way, with the image on top instead of on the below. And had to add `height: null` `width: null` to make the image shrink to the screen size. Awesome, thanks! I gave the answer an 'up', I don't have enough reputation. Have a good day, mate!

Comment: @Carlove you‘re welcome. But you could accept the answer, then i would earn points:)

Comment: You just need to click on the check mark beside my answer ;)